# In chatter feed (in any post of comment field) , I am unable to attach 114KB file. It throws the error. Please some tell me why?

Tags: apex, visualforce, email, force.com, chatter

The error is :-for files exceeding 2GB, please chatter or contact BMC directly

Answer (score 0):

First Check your profile level. And check the link : https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=limits_collaboration_files.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. But the file size is 114 KB, still i got the above error.